# Autowired annotation return null object in asynchronous task

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, dependency-injection

I have nullPointerException on my databaseNotificationServices object and I don't know why. I tried with @Service and @Component annotations on class, but autowired returns null object. Do you know where is the problem?

```
@Service
public class MyAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Autowired
    private DatabaseNotificationServices databaseNotificationServices;
    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.class);


    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable ex, Method method, Object... params) {
        LOG.error("Threw exception in async method Method Name:: " + method.getName() + " " + ErrorExceptionBuilder.buildErrorResponse(ex));
        try {
            databaseNotificationServices.createNotificationRole(UserRole.ADMIN, NotificationType.ERROR,  "Error durign conversion of dat in mat file, please check the log file!", "Mat conversion error");
        } catch (QueryException e) {
            ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
            LOG.error("Threw exception in ZipAndMat::createZipAndMat, problem with notification: " + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the poblem due to asynchronous task? In the other class I use @Autowired without problem

Comment: The problem is likely due to you instantiating `MyAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` yourself instead of getting it from the context. Until you show us otherwise, we can only assume that is your issue and the duplicate explains the reason.

Comment: Yes, to set asynchronous exception handle I have in my configuration class
public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new MyAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

Comment: Well, there's your problem. See the duplicate which explains why that's a problem and how to fix it.